# Python batch script to delete Attributes

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, table, batch, delete

I currently have a script that will select and delete all the values less than 0.1 in a column. The script below works, however it specifies a specific .shp, I want to batch this so it runs through all the shapefiles in a geodatabase

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Sr90_contour","NEW_SELECTION",'"Contour" < 0.1')
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("Sr90_contour")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the GDB as your workspace and then use the [`arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) function to get all the names of the features in that GDB:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.worskapce = r'C:\path\to\my.gdb'

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "lyr")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '"Contour" < 0.1')
    arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("lyr")
```

Note that this will only work if all your feature classes have the `Contour` field.

Comment: Thanks, However when I run that I get the following error...…... runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 6, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7221, in SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: The value cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.

Comment: You need to create an in-memory feature layer for every feature class first before making a selection on it.  See [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm)

Comment: @JHR See the edit I just made to the question taking into accout the comment from mdholl6188. Also, delete your answer, as it does not really answer your question but is rather a comment or edit.